# Implementation of datatypes in PHP

Tags: php, types, store, implementation

I wanted to know about Data Type **implementation** in PHP so I need a few resources(books websites and ...). what I want is not what data types PHP support or how to use them, it's the implementation and how all these things is done by PHP. I want to know how they are stored in memory and the very detail things about it(I already know PHP pretty good). That would be great if you could lead me where can I find this information.

Comment: What about read the source of php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a couple of articles on data types in PHP from [PHP Rocks](http://www.php-rocks.com/types_in_php.php) and [dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/understanding-php-data-types.html). An interesting aside when it comes to data types in PHP is [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) which will force a data type to be used for a function parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what I really want to know is how these data types are stored in memory. (how many bits are used, how PHP describe them before putting them in memory. like a float number in memory that need a few changes before storing)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere like [IRC Maxwell's blog](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/03/phps-source-code-for-php-developers_21.html) would be a good starting point, together with [nikic's blog](http://nikic.github.com/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html) posts